# Merge 2 Open source script?

Tags: php, image, open-source, hosting

I need some help on using two open sources scripts for a small project.

- [The first one is an a URL shortener with image hosting function](http://code.google.com/p/kissabe/)
- [The second is a pure image hosting script](http://chevereto.com/)

The first script is object orientated code, and I'll like to know if it's a good approach or should I hire somebody to merge both, means replace the image hosting function of one with the second script.

I can't figure this out as I'm not a coder yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just "merge" two separated code fragments/projects into one single without programming experience. Analyze the two scripts an find out how to use it. Then you can think of an interaction between the two scripts. If it's clean object oriented code its usually no big deal.

Answer (score 4):

Find a programmer.

Things don't just magically work, so get somebody that understands what needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks elmuerte, that's exactly what I was trying to find out.do I need a coder to change this code with the chevereto code or the code is better as it is, and I should rather look for a designer. Got told, the code is probably better for my purpose, as It's OO coding, and chevereto is procedural and not really better for my purposes. I just ask the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't merge scripts. Use a script for a purpose and use another script for another purpose. Keeping the external scripts apart also enables you to update them without (hopfully) breaking your application.